# Amount of combinations out of seven when only five can be in at one time

Tags: probability, factorial

I'm a circus performer, currently working in a show which has 5 roles in it. In the cast we have 7 performers who change roles daily so that two people get a day off every day. We have been trying to work out how many combinations are possible with factorials, but we don't know how to constrain the 7 performers to the 5 roles.
Let me know if that doesn't make sense, but if you know the answer, please show your working too!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: Nope! I mean, in real life it does - each person only has two roles, but I feel like that's far more complicated

Answer (score 1):

Assuming order doesn't matter, the answer is $7\choose5$ = $\frac{7!}{2!5!}$

Comment: As a courtesy, let me add that ${7 \choose 5} = 21$.